# BeautifulSoup: Get the time and date of a column that shows "x minutes ago"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some info of this website: https://cryptoslam.io/nba-top-shot/sales As you can see, in the fist column, 'Sold', I get some information of the time and date of the row. The problem is in this column this information is shown by text with like "2 minutes ago", "x seconds ago" or "six months ago".

I would like to create a dataframe where the column 'Sold' shows the exact time and date. Instead of "one minute ago" I would like to get "11-3-2021, 17:17h" or something like this. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of parsing the HTML, look at the network activity when you interact with the page: the JS code makes API calls to the server. Use these API endpoints to get structured data.

Comment: If you only saw the earlier version of my answer, please check out the new version.  I found a Python module that does what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup won't do this for you itself.  It's responsible for pulling whatever is on the page out of the page for you.  It doesn't deal with any sorts of data conversions.  So you will need a module that parses these strings and converts them to date/time values.

I found the module that will do this for you.  You can install it with:

```
pip install dateparse
```

Then it's super simple to use it:

```
import dateparser
import datetime

# Display current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)

# Display result of parsing a human-readable relative time
# to go back two hours
date = dateparser.parse('2 hours ago')
print(date)
```

Result:

```
2021-03-11 09:05:05.884789
2021-03-11 07:05:05.942474
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is great. Now how I have to figure out how to parse all the data of the column 'Sold' creating a new column 'Time' that takes the text of 'Sold' and converse to datetime in my dataframe

Comment: Solved. It was using this: df['Date'] = df1['Sold'].apply(lambda x :dateparser.parse(x)) Thanks again!

Comment: Cool beans.  Glad I could be of help!